# Python & Matplot: How can I draw a simple shape by points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just want to draw simple shape by points, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
hexagon = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,0),(1,-1)]
l_shape = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(3,1),(3,0)]
concave = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(2,1),(2,3),(3,3),(3,0)]

for points in [rectangle, hexagon, l_shape, concave]:
    # 1. Can I get rid of the zip? plot directly by points 
    # 2. How can I make the shape complete?
    xs, ys = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, 'o')
    plt.plot(xs, ys, '-')

    automin, automax = plt.xlim()
    plt.xlim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
    automin, automax = plt.ylim()
    plt.ylim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
    # Can I display the shapes 2 in 1 line?
    plt.show()
```

My question is 
[image]

1. How can I get rid of the `*zip`? I mean, directyly draw by points, rather than 2 array.
2. How to make these shapes `complete`? Since I'm looping through all the points, the first and last cannot connect together, how can I do it?
3. Can I draw the shape without giving the specific points order?(Something like `convex hull`?)

Comment: why do you want to get rid of `*zip`? It is a convenient way to plot points and connect them with lines.

Comment: @Alik I mean something like this`plt.plot([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)], 'o')`, so I can directly pass points to `plot`, without `zipping` them.

Comment: then do `plt.plot(*zip(*(points+points[:1])), marker='o')` instead of `xs, ys = zip(*points)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, 'o')
    plt.plot(xs, ys, '-')`

Comment: This will solve #1 and #2. As for #3 - I do not get what your really want. Convex hull for `l_shape` will be different, it won't contain `(1,1)` point

Comment: @Alik, Thanks. For #3, I'm just trying to descript what I want. Certainly `Convexl hull` woud suffice. I think a more proper description would be `draw simple shape without ordering points`?

Comment: Take a look at getting the ccworder from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040412/how-to-draw-the-largest-polygon-from-a-set-of-points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below doesn't use temporary variables `xs` and `ys`, but a direct tuple unpacking. Also I add first point from `points` list to make shapes complete.

```
rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
hexagon = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,0),(1,-1)]
l_shape = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(3,1),(3,0)]
concave = [(0,0),(0,3),(1,3),(1,1),(2,1),(2,3),(3,3),(3,0)]

for points in [rectangle, hexagon, l_shape, concave]:
    plt.plot(*zip(*(points+points[:1])), marker='o')

    automin, automax = plt.xlim()
    plt.xlim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
    automin, automax = plt.ylim()
    plt.ylim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)

    plt.show()
```

Provide this answer as an alternative leekaiinthesky's post

Answer (score 3):

To close the shape, just add the first point again at the end of the list:

```
# rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)]
```

`plt.plot` takes a list of x coordinates and a list of y coordinates. I would say that the way you're doing it now is already the way of doing it "by points rather than 2 arrays". Because if you wanted to do it without `zip`, it would look like this:

```
rectangleX = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
rectangleY = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
plt.plot(rectangleX, rectangleY, 'o')
plt.plot(rectangleX, rectangleY, '-')
```

**Update:**

For better polygon support, use the [patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) module [[example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/path_patch_demo.html)]. This may be more along the lines of what you're looking for. By default (`closed = True`), it will close the path for you, and it also allows you to add vertices directly to a list (not two separate lists):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Polygon(rectangle))

automin, automax = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
automin, automax = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But I feel adding the first point again is quite repetative, is there more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Does this need the points be in a specific order? So it can displayed as a shape, and there won't be lines across(lie in) the shape?

Comment: The edges will be drawn in the order provided, same as what you had before.

Comment: Got it, sadly it does not solve my #3 problem. I think it is a quite big one. I'll edit it out and make it a standalone question.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040412/how-to-draw-the-largest-polygon-from-a-set-of-points or this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky well, it won't solve the problem, because not all points in OP's shapes are on respective convex hulls.

Comment: I already tried the `convex hull`, it does not help with `L-shape` and `Concave`.